# From Ankara to Kayseri by bus

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, turkey, ankara

I'm planning to arrive to Ankara by airplane soon, and then I will have to get to Kayseri by bus as soon as possible.

Should I buy bus ticket on the station, or online in advance (which option is better/cheaper)? My airplane lands at 5am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I buy bus ticket on the station, or online in advance (which
> option is better/cheaper)?

I don't think the price will change. I would choose to buy ticket on the station, you can easily find tickets during those morning hours. You can use [Kamil Koç](https://www.flixbus.com.tr/) or [Süha Turizm](https://www.suha.com.tr/) as a firm. The downside of buying the ticket online is that you *may* be late for the bus due to traffic. But if you buy a ticket for 2-3 hours after you get off the plane, I think it will be okay.

For Esenboğa Airport to AŞTİ (Ankara intercity terminal) you have 2 options; public transport or taxi.

With public transport, you can use [Belko Air](https://www.belkoair.com/en) ([preferably 442-A, if not 442-K but this takes more time](https://www.belkoair.com/tr/hizmet-noktalari)) or [Havaş](http://www.havas.net/en/Pages/default.aspx). They probably take 60-80 minutes to reach AŞTİ and you will pay 12 Turkish Lira.

With taxi, it probably takes 30-40 minutes (depends on traffic) and you will pay around 150 Turkish Lira.

Here is the root that Google Maps show from Esenboğa Airport to AŞTİ Terminal: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Bal%C4%B1khisar+Mh.,+Ankara+Esenbo%C4%9Fa+Havaliman%C4%B1+(ESB),+%C3%96zal+Bulvar%C4%B1,+Akyurt%2FAnkara/A%C5%9Fti+Terminali,+Emek,+%C3%87ankaya%2FAnkara/@40.0146368,32.7434776,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x40820fdad0c982a9:0xf13ed2bab75c76d6!2m2!1d32.9916726!2d40.1244399!1m5!1m1!1s0x14d34f3684a62bc3:0x3b6e737435e4e8d7!2m2!1d32.8144643!2d39.9181567!3e0

[image]

Comment: Even if you're late, most bus companies allow free cancellation up to an hour before so you should be able to cancel and rebook in time.